# Assume $f,g, fg\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\widehat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Prove that $\widehat{fg}=(2\pi)^{-n}\widehat{f}*\widehat{g}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

To demonstrate this exercise we will use the following theorem:

***Theorem: Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and assume that $\widehat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $f$ is equivalent to a continuous function. Therefore, we assume with no loss of generality that $f$ is continuous. Then for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $$f(x)=(2\pi)^{-n}\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\cdot\xi}\,d\xi}.$$***

by the previous theorem and by definition of Fourier transform

\begin{align*}
\widehat{fg}(\xi)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)g(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,dx\\ &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left[(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\eta)e^{ix\cdot\eta}\,d\eta\right]g(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,dx\\&=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x)e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\eta)e^{ix\cdot\eta}\,d\eta\right]\,dx\\&=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\eta)g(x)e^{-ix(\xi-\eta)}\,d\eta\right]\,dx\\&=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\eta)g(x)e^{-ix\cdot(\xi-\eta)}\,dx\right]\,d\eta\\&=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\eta)\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x)e^{-ix\cdot(\xi-\eta)}\,dx\right]\,d\eta\\&=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}(\eta)\widehat{g}(\xi-\eta)\,d\eta\\&=(2\pi)^{-n}\left(\widehat{f}*\widehat{g}\right)(\xi).
\end{align*}
**Remark:** Note that Fubini's theorem has been applied to the fifth line of the chain of equalities above, which is possible since $\widehat{f}(\eta)g(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ which implies that $\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}g}\hspace{.2cm}$ exists. Indeed:
\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}g\right|\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n}|\widehat{f}g|=\|\widehat{f}g\|_{L^1}\leq\|\widehat{f}\|_{L^1}\|g\|_{L^1}<\infty\qquad (1).
\end{equation}
**My concerns about the above proof are:**

1. *The chain of equalities immediately above is correct to justify that $\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{f}g}$ exists?* *Also I'm not sure if the last inequality in $(1)$ is true.*
2. *Did I apply Fubbini's theorem correctly?*

Comment: Yes and yes. The argument is fine.

Comment: The argument is not correct: You need to argue  why is $fg\in L_1$? Hint: The Fourier inversion theorem not only tells you that $f$ is equivalent to a continuous function, but also that $f$ is I fact equivalent to a function in $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: The argument is not entirely fine!

Comment: @OliverDiaz That is a very mnior point. The inversion formula tells you that $f$ is a bounded measurable function so $fg$ is integrable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: That is the what I spell out in my comment. Once the simple, yet not obvious, fact that $fg$ is integrable, then one apply inversion theorem again and set things up to apply  Fubini-Tonelli's theorem. Without that, the first line of computations is wobbly.

Comment: Why does $||\hat{f}g||_1 \leq ||\hat{f}||_1 ||g||_1$ ?

Comment: @blamethelag This is where I have one of my doubts, this is one of the reasons why I have posted the test of this exercise. Although in my opinion this would be a consequence of Hölder's inequality.

Comment: @Mathstudy I think it is false in general. If you take $\phi \in L^1 \setminus L^2$ this would give you $||\phi^2||_1 \leq ||\phi||_1^2$. Hölder inequality gives you $||\hat{f}g||_1 \leq ||\hat{f}||_\infty ||g||_1$ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two observatios:

1. Since $\widehat{f}\in L_1$, the Fourier inversion theorem implies that $f\in\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$; hence $fg\in L_1$ and $\|fg\|_1\leq \|f\|_\infty\|g\|_1$. This makes line 1 in your chain of identities valid.
2. $\widehat{f}(\eta) g(x)\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ by the Fubini-Tonelli theorem, for the iterated integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\widehat{f}(\eta)||g(x)|\,d\eta dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\widehat{f}(\eta)|\,d\eta\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|g(x)|\,dx=\|\widehat{f}\|_1\|g\|_1<\infty$$ by assumption on $\widehat{f}$.